# Making stops on the way from Machu Picchu to Cusco

Tags: trains, peru

I'll be taking a train from Machu Picchu to Poroy.

I was wondering if it is possible to make stops along the way to see some of the sites. Specifically, I would like to go to Moray/Sacred Valley on the way home. I'm totally willing to combine train travel and taxi rides but would need to end up back in Cusco.

Comment: Do you mean that you're buying a single ticket from Machu Picchu to Poroy and want to get off at some stop in between?

Comment: I haven't purchased the ticket yet. I'll be in Machu Picchu and am heading back to Cusco. I was wondering what the best way to see sites along the way is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would help to know when you are planning to travel. For example between Jan 2 and April 30 2017 the [PeruRail](http://www.perurail.com/) 'train' service (The Hiram Bingham) is bimodal with a bus from/to Poroy to/from Ollantaytambo and train from/to there. [IncaRail](http://www.incarail.com/) also offers services from Ollantaytambo to Machu Picchu.

Singles are available from both operators.

You may however prefer to return with PeruRail to [Urubamba](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Urubamba,+Cusco,+Peru/Moray,+Maras,+Cusco,+Peru/@-13.3213159,-72.2214094,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x916ddce02c0b73b7:0xa2f520ed807a2bcb!2m2!1d-72.1156281!2d-13.3057641!1m5!1m1!1s0x916dc3a5b4a291c9:0x14c05f95d6a68a83!2m2!1d-72.1971438!2d-13.3298569!3e0), since from there Moray is only about 40 minutes by road, and then work your own way back to Cuzco from Moray.

Further details [here](http://www.seat61.com/Peru.htm).